# media queries to control div width

Tags: html, css

A div and its children inputs need to have `width:100%` when screen is less than 600px wide. Why the code below fails to do that?

I need to have the dives side by side when screen is above 600px and below each other 100% width on smaller screen. And thus their input contents.

Thanks

```css
/* include the padding in the total size of all elements */
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* prevnet page refresh when overscrolling happens */
body {
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

#contact {
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: rgb(235, 115, 205);
}
#vehicle {
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
}

@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="contact">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone numbers">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  
    <div id="vehicle">
    <input type="text" placeholder="plate, vehicleId">
    <input type="text" placeholder="date, make, modle">
    <input type="text" placeholder="engine size, code, drive">
    <input type="text" placeholder="color, shape">
  </div>
  
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase your media query selector accuracy, something like `div#contact, div#vehicle { width: 100%; }` instead of just `div`. The media query css works just fine, but gets overwritten by the more accurate one above (selecting by an element ID is more accurate than selecting by element types).

```css
/* include the padding in the total size of all elements */
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* prevnet page refresh when overscrolling happens */
body {
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

#contact {
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: rgb(235, 115, 205);
}
#vehicle {
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
}

@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div#contact,
  div#vehicle {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="contact">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone numbers">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  
    <div id="vehicle">
    <input type="text" placeholder="plate, vehicleId">
    <input type="text" placeholder="date, make, modle">
    <input type="text" placeholder="engine size, code, drive">
    <input type="text" placeholder="color, shape">
  </div>
  
  </body>
```